# Handling Unhandled Akka Errors in Play Framework with Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka

I'm using Akka in my play application and mostly it's working out really. However, one challenge I have is unhandled exceptions.

I use the ask pattern like this in the controller:

```
(searcher ? request) map {
```

Where searcher is an actor created by the actor system.

Searcher then sends a message to another actor. And this is the problem. How can I get the unhandled exception back to the controller so I know there was an unhandled exception and can tell the user something went wrong.

As far as I can tell, every actor needs a reference to the anonymous actor created by the ask pattern in the code above.

Normally errors would propagate up to the supervisor. But in this case, the supervisor would have no reference the anonymous actor created by the ask. So it seems each actor will need a reference to the anonymous actor and catch and send their own errors (losing the benefits of supervision hierarchy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send errors wrapped in akka.actor.Status.Failure from your searcher to the sender automatically using pipeto:

```
Future { ... } pipeTo sender
```

or in case of chained processing:

```
(anotherSearcher ? anotherRequest) pipeTo sender
```

or you can handle and send errors manually:

```
try {
  ...
} catch {
  case e: Exception ⇒
    sender ! akka.actor.Status.Failure(e)
}
```

And then you can handle them in your controller:

```
val theFuture = searcher ? request

theFuture onSuccess {
  case ... =>
    self ! SuccessMessage(...)
    // or process in a different way (don't forget that this will be executed in a separate thread - e.g. don't close over the sender)
}

theFuture onFailure {
  case e =>
   self ! FailureMessage(e)
   // or process in a different way (don't forget that this will be executed in a separate thread - e.g. don't close over the sender)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How about the case when the searcher sends a message to someone else who doesn't have a reference to the original sender?

Comment: In this case someone else can reply through searcher (using pipeTo in searcher - (anotherSearcher ? anotherRequest) pipeTo sender).

Answer (score 0):

Normally it does not matters for your users where there error is. All you need is to show 500 error page. You can use ask timeout to do this.

Also, you can log error from certain actor to your log and investigate it by operations.

So, you simple do not need to know what there error is when you ask your searcher. All you need to know is timeout exception.

Comment: You need to know. But you dont need to know in `(searcher ? request)`. All you need is to log error in your actors no matters who sent the message